# Linear combination?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying free algebras and algebras defined by generators and relations and there is this example in the book that I'm reading that I'm having trouble to understand why can I affirme that every element in A is a linear combination of x, y, xy and yx.

Let F be a field and $A := F<x, y\ |\ x^2 = 0,\ y^2 = 0,\ xy + yx = 1>$. A concrete example
of a pair of elements satisfying these relations are the matrix units E12 and E21 in
M2(F). Let us show that A is actually isomorphic to M2(F). We begin by noticing that
xyx = x and yxy = y. Hence it follows that every element in A is a linear combination
of x, y, xy, and yx.

I can see that in with the matrix but not in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nonzero monomial elements come in the form
$$x^{a_1}y^{b_1}x^{a_2}y^{b_2}\cdots x^{a_m}y^{b_m}$$
where some $a_i,b_i$ may be $0$. Well we can see that $a_i,b_i\leq 1$ for all $i$ because $x^2=y^2=0$. Thus elements look like $(xy)^k$, $(xy)^kx$, $(yx)^k$, $(yx)^ky$. Say we have $$(xy)^2=xyxy$$
Since $xyx=x$, this is just $xy$. Similarly, any alternating sequence of length more than $2$ can be simplified to $x$, $y$, $xy$, or $yx$, because the sequences of length $3$, namely $xyx$ and $yxy$, can be reduced to length $1$.